# implement Android home-screen widget with javascript or other language

Tags: javascript, vue.js, android-widget

I want to develop an Android App. And I want to build home-screen widget.

It can be implemented with Native Android. But I prefer to use javascript to develop.

It's there any other solution that use javascript to build home-screen widget?

I prefer to use Vue.js, Framework7, or Corona(Framework of Lua).

Thanks for help.

---

framework7: https://framework7.io/

Corona: https://coronalabs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Along with Vuejs you can try these:

[Vue-material](https://vuematerial.io/)
[vuetifyjs](https://vuetifyjs.com/)

Comment: That's really good suggestion for me to develop vue app. But that's still not solve my problem. But still thank you.